# how to remove text from input text box using css

Tags: html, css

```css
.complete {
  content: 'complete'
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Complete Purchase" id="btn_complete" class="complete">
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YI7O.png)

Here the button text is "Complete Purchase". i want to remove "Purchase". i need only Complete. by using css only. i have tired using css. Please see the above snippet

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of your problem? Have you attempted to solve it?

Comment: show some code, your attempt to solve, atleast give us something to work with mate.

Comment: This is really not what CSS is for... The best would be to modify the HTML, then probable modify it with JavaScript, and the "hackiest" solution would be via CSS, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anywhere that you can replace a part of something with css, But with this you can change all your text in an element:

```
.yourElement {content: 'complete'}
```

But It can completely be done using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It is not either the matter of css or js or anything......The problem is, what do you want to change?.... if you want to change the text of a button, just go to your html file and edit the text. Or If the html file is isolated from you, and you have just the access of js directories or css directories, then use  style  `content:'complete'` or use js.